# git graceful rebase/complete merge to branch

Tags: git, git-merge, rebase

Goodday,

I am currently trying to figure out how I can 'overwrite' a branch without using something drastic like 'rebase'.

For example:

```
branch::master
|- dir_a
|  |- file_a
|  |- file_b
|- file_c

branch::dev
|- dir_a
|  |- file_b
|- file_c        [edited compared to branch::master]


branch::master   [after merge from branch::dev with strategy 'ours' (keep changes from branch::dev)]
|- dir_a
|  |- file_a     [is also merged, but should be deleted]
|  |- file_b
|- file_c        [edited version from branch::dev]
```

To fix the above problem, I could do a 'rebase', but that would break loats of stuff, since the master(head) branch is not a private/personal one.

So the question is: *Is there a good way to completly overwrite/replace the content of the master branch so that dependencies on the current master branch are not broken?*

---

information that may influence the possibilities:

- there may be a difference of multiple commits between both branches (the amount is also unknown)
- preferably the 'dev' branch should proceed to exist (also for dependency reasons).
- preferably the history of the master branch should stay intact

If there is any additional clarification needed, feel free to ask.
Thanks for thinking with!

Comment: Before merging `dev` into `master`. Have you tried merging `master` into `dev`? So you'd do merge right before merge left (left is master).

Comment: `@Praveen Premaratne` interesting, I see what you are trying to achieve. problem is that both branches might have removed files. Would that approuch still work?

Comment: That would work, but you'll obviously gonna get a merge conflict at some point tho. Even with that, it will preserve commit history and won't cause other users headache of hard resetting heads like rebase do.

Comment: I just tried it with a local test. And unfortunatly that doesn't work in all cases. In my case `master` added `file_a` after `dev` modified `file_c`. So in the history of `dev` there is no 'delete file_a' entry. Therefore it just gets merged without conflicts.

Comment: ok, so at what point was `file_a` deleted and which branch was it?

Comment: `file_a` was deleted on branch `master` after branch `dev` was cloned which modified `file_c`. in the end I want branch `master` to contain the exact content of branch `dev` but without breaking external dependencies (caused by resetting / rebase)

Comment: when you did the merge `dev` into `master`, was there a conflict?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210031/discussion-between-n247s-and-praveen-premaratne).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a good way to completly overwrite/replace the content of the master branch ...

There is more than one, but before you pick any, you need to be clear on what you mean by *branch* and *content*.

The thing to keep in mind about branches is that each branch *name* simply says *my latest commit is _____* (fill in the blank with a raw commit hash ID).  The commits that are "on" the branch depend on that *commit*.

Every commit has a unique hash ID.  That hash ID means *that* commit, and not any other commit.  Once a commit is made, *no part it can ever change*.  All commits are totally frozen for all time.  Commits are mostly permanent, too: at most, you can stop using a commit, and take away the means of *finding* that commit, as we'll see in a moment.

Each commit holds two things: as its main data, a full and complete snapshot of all files, and as its metadata—information *about* the commit.  This includes the name and email address of the person who made it, and the log message explaining *why* they made that commit.  But most important of all, at least for Git, is this:  When you, or anyone, make a *new* commit, Git records the raw hash ID of its immediate *parent* commit.  That hash ID is the hash ID of the commit you had out just a moment ago, that *was* the last commit in the branch.  Again, no part of this data (snapshot) or metadata (including parent hash ID) can ever change from here on out—so this means that *this* commit remembers the *previous* branch-tip commit.

Hence, the "content of a branch" can be:

- the raw hash ID of the last commit in the branch; or
- that hash ID and hence that commit, plus the hash ID stored in that commit and hence the previous commit, plus another hash ID stored in that commit and hence another previous commit, plus ...

If we draw these commits—which requires making assumptions about their hash IDs; here I'll just replace each actual hash ID with single uppercase letters—we get this kind of picture:

```
             I--J   <-- master
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             K--L   <-- dev
```

That is, the *name* `master` holds the raw hash ID of commit `J` (whatever it really is).  Commit `J` holds the raw hash ID of commit `I`, which holds the hash ID of commit `H`.  Meanwhile the name `dev` holds the hash ID of commit `L`, which holds that of `K`, which holds that of `H`.

Note that commits up through `H` are on *both* branches.

In this situation, the branches join up at `H`, at least, when viewed the way Git views them: starting at the *end* and working backwards, one commit at a time.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, the index contains the files' names, their mode (+x or -x), and a *reference to* the frozen-format content.

---

#### How branches typically grow

To make a new commit, you might start with `git checkout name`.  Let's say the name in this case is `master`.  This finds the *commit to which the name points*—in this case, `J`—and copies the read-only contents of the commit out of the commit, into Git's index and into your work-tree.  The work-tree is where you can see and edit your files.  This also attaches the special name `HEAD` to the name `master`:

```
             I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             K--L   <-- dev
```

Git can now see that the *current branch* is `master` (by seeing where `HEAD` is attached) and the *current commit* is `J` (by seeing where `master` points).  Your work-tree now has the files that *you* work with—ordinary files, not freeze-dried (compressed and Git-only) committed files—and in Git's index, there are copies<sup>1</sup> of the freeze-dried files from `J`, ready to go into a new commit.

You can now modify the work-tree all you like.  When you're done, you can run `git add` on various files.  This copies each added files' *content* back into Git's index, squishing them down to the freeze-dried form that Git will store in a commit, replacing the previous copy.  Or, you can `git add` a new file, or `git rm` an existing file; either way, Git updates the index accordingly.

Then, you run `git commit`.  Git simply packages up whatever is in the *index*, adds your name and the current time, adds your log message, and writes that out as a new commit.  The new commit's *parent* is the *current commit* and the hash ID is a unique checksum of the new commit's content, which can no longer ever be changed.  We'll call this new commit `N` (skipping over `M`).  `N` points back to `J`:

```
                  N
                 /
             I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             K--L   <-- dev
```

but now we get the trick that makes branches useful: **Git now writes the new commit's hash ID into the branch name.**  So we now have:

```
             I--J--N   <-- master (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             K--L   <-- dev
```

Note that `HEAD` has not changed: it's still attached to `master`.

Now let's *get rid of* commit `N`.  It won't actually go away—it will still be in our repository—but we'll arrange for the *name* `master` to identify commit `J` again.  To do that, we find the actual hash ID of `J`, or any proxy for it, and use `git reset --hard`:

```
git reset --hard <hash-of-J>
```

Now we have:

```
                  N   [abandoned]
                 /
             I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             K--L   <-- dev
```

If you do this in *your* repository, without using `git push` to *send* new commit `N` to some *other* Git repository, *only you will have commit `N`*.  No one else will ever know you did this!

#### Using `git reset` arbitrarily

You can, with `git reset`, move *any* branch to *any* commit.  But if you move a branch "backwards", like we just did, the commits that "fall off the end" become hard to find.  Suppose you forced the name `master` to point to commit `L`.  How, then, would you find commit `J`?  What about commit `I`?  They seem to be gone!

This *could* be what you want.  But if some *other* Git repository *already has* commits `I` and `J`, perhaps someone using that repository has built *new* commits that link back to `J`.  They won't appreciate you asking them to forget all their commits, along with `I` and `J`.

If it's OK to make everyone else forget `I` and `J`, you can just reset `master` to point to `L`.  You then have to use `git push --force` or equivalent to convince some *other* Git repository to forget `I` and `J` (and maybe additional commits) too, and everyone else who's using a clone of this repository needs to make sure *their* Git forgets `I` and `J`, and so on.

**This is the fastest and easiest way to make `master` match `dev`, but it is also the most disruptive to everyone else.  Git "likes" it when branches grow and "dislikes" it when they lose commits.**

#### How merge works (abbreviated)

Let's look now at what happens if you run `git merge dev` (with `master` pointing to `J` again).  Git needs, for this merge operation, *three* input commits.  One is your current commit, which merge calls `ours`.  One is any other commit of your choice, which merge calls `theirs`.  The *third* one—which in some sense is the *first one;* at least, it gets number 1 in a moment—Git finds on its own.

By using `git merge dev`, you selected commit `L` as the `theirs` commit.  That's because the name `dev` selects commit `L`.  Git now works backwards from *both* branch tips to find the *best **shared** commit*, which in this case is clearly commit `H`.  Git calls this the *merge base*.

Remember that each commit holds a snapshot.  So commit `H` has a snapshot, and commit `J` has one, and commit `L` has one.  Git can, at any time, *compare any two snapshots* to see what is different.  The command that does this for you is `git diff`.  The merge operation wants to know what is different, so it runs the internal equivalent of:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-J>   # what we changed on master
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-L>   # what they changed on dev
```

Git can now *combine these two sets of changes*, and apply the *combined* changes to the snapshot in `H` (not `J`, not `L`, but `H`: the merge base).  If we added a file and they didn't, Git adds the file.  If we deleted a file and they didn't, Git deletes the file.  If they changed a file and we didn't, Git changes the file.

The result, if all goes well, is the combination of our changes and their changes.  Git will stuff this result back into the index—which is the place from which Git makes commits—while also updating our work-tree so that we can see what it did.  Then, since all went well, Git makes a new commit.

The new commit, which we'll call `M` for `merge`, has not one but *two* parents.  The *first* parent is the same as usual: `M` links back to existing commit `J`, which is where `master` was a moment ago.  But Git adds commit `L`, the one we chose to merge, as a *second* parent.  So now the picture is:<sup>2</sup>

```
             I--J
            /    \
...--F--G--H      M   <-- master (HEAD)
            \    /
             K--L   <-- dev
```

Commit `M` has a snapshot.  Its snapshot was made *by Git* (rather than by you), which *combined* changes from the common starting point—the merge base—and applied the combined changes to the merge-base snapshot.

If you get *merge conflicts*, the index takes on an expanded role and helps with resolving the conflicts.  It becomes up to you, not Git, to determine the final snapshot in ultimate merge commit `M`.  But if there aren't any merge conflicts, Git will normally make the merge on its own.  *Normally* is an important word here.

---

<sup>2</sup>Commit `N` still exists, but with no way to *find* it, you can't see it any more, and we don't need to bother to draw it in.  Eventually, Git will remove it entirely—typically some time after at least 30 days have passed.  Until then, you can get it back if you want it: you just have to find its hash ID.

---

#### That's a normal merge; you may want an overwriting merge

Suppose that you could tell Git: *Start the merge, but don't make merge commit `M` yet.*  Git would find the merge base as usual, combine your changes and their changes as usual, and update your work-tree and Git's index as usual ... and then stop, without making the commit.

You can do exactly that, using `git merge --no-commit`.  Once you have done that, you can *replace* the merge result with whatever you like.  Put any file you like into your work-tree, and use `git add` to have Git copy it into the index.  The index copy, which is what will go into the new merge commit, now matches whatever file you put in the work-tree.

You can add new files and remove files entirely here.  Whatever you do, it's up to *you:* you control everything at this point.  You can make the merge have any content you want.

What you want—according to your question, anyway; think about whether this is *really* what you want—is to completely ignore the difference from the merge base `H` to your commit `J`, and just take the difference from `H` to *their* comimt `L`.  Of course, that will match the snapshot in commit `L` exactly.

There is a fast and easy way, using `git merge -s ours`, to tell Git that it should *completely ignore their branch's changes* and just use your version of everything, i.e., to take commit `J`.  Unfortunately, that's the opposite of what you want here: you're asking for a way to *completely ignore your branch's changes* and just use *their* version of everything, i.e., to take commit `L`.

Fortunately, there's a rather magical command<sup>3</sup> you can use that *is* fast and easy, to get what you want here:

```
git merge --no-commit dev
git read-tree --reset -u dev
```

This `git read-tree -u` command tells Git: *Replace the index and my work-tree contents with the files that are stored in the commit I name here.*  The `--reset` option tells Git to throw out conflict entries, if the merge generated merge conflicts (and should be harmless if not).  So now the index, and your work-tree, match the snapshot in `L`.  Now you can finish the merge:<sup>4</sup>

```
git merge --continue
```

This makes new merge commit `M` from the content stored in the index, which—thanks to the `-u` option of the `git read-tree` command—you can also see in your work-tree.  So now you have:

```
             I--J
            /    \
...--F--G--H      M   <-- master (HEAD)
            \    /
             K--L   <-- dev
```

where the *content* of commit `M` exactly matches the *content* of commit `L`.  The *first parent* of `M` is still `J`, and the second is still `L`, as they would be for any other merge.  But you've "killed off" the changes you had in `I` and `J`, while only *adding* a commit to `master`.  All other Gits will be happy enough to *add* commit `M` to *their* collections of commits.

---

<sup>3</sup>It's not really magic at all.  It's a *plumbing* command, meant for use in scripts, rather than for users.  The read-tree command is astonishingly complicated, though: it implements (some of) merging, subtree operations, and all kinds of other cleverness.  It's a significant part of the reason that the index, which is otherwise kind of a pain, exists.

<sup>4</sup>If you like, you can run `git commit` instead.  In old Git versions that don't have `git merge --continue`, you will have to use `git commit`.  It is OK to use `git commit` directly: all `git merge --continue` does is check first that there is a merge to finish, then runs `git commit` for you.  Using `git merge --continue`, you check that you really are finishing a merge.

---

#### Consider this option as well

Suppose you *don't* want a merge.  That is, suppose you want to keep the progression:

```
             I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             K--L   <-- dev
```

the way it is, but add a new commit `O` to `master`, whose *parent* is `J`, but whose *content* matches that of `L` on `dev`?

This is easy to do, too.  Having freshly done a `git checkout master`, so that your index and work-tree match `J`, you now run:

```
git read-tree -u dev
```

(with no preceding merge there can't be merge conflicts, so `--reset` should not be required).

This replaces Git's index and your work-tree contents, reading them from commit `L`, just as we did in the merge example.  Now you can run `git commit` to make `O`:

```
             I--J--O   <-- master (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             K--L   <-- dev
```

The *content* of commit `O` now matches the content of `L`; the *history* obtained by starting at `master`—commit `O`—and working backwards reads `O`, then `J`, then `I`, then `H`, and so on.

(Which of these options do you want?  That's up to you.)

Comment: That is an ellaborate and verry clear explanation about the different ways to solve the problem, thanks! I went with the second last option: `merge + read-tree`. might be good to mention that in order to 'read' the tree index you need to specify a 'merge strategy' as well. either `-m --reset --prefix`. This is I assume to account for changes made after the 'merge call'? As it doesn't make any difference when no changes are made between the `merge` and `read-tree` call. If I am misstaken I would love to hear though.

Comment: Ah, you'll need these options if you've had merge conflicts, I think. I use read-tree so rarely that I can never remember its various conditions. It looks like `--reset` is the key for merge conflicts. I added the appropriate `--reset`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a merge without doing a real merge, just joining history by selecting the "ours" merge strategy:

```
git checkout dev
git merge -s ours master
```

Your history will record a merge of dev to master, history of both branches will stay intact, but the file contents will look like `master` never existed (they only reflect `dev` content)